# How to edit metadata of image in iOS8?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary

```
ALAssetsLibrary *lib = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [lib assetForURL:nil resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
        NSDictionary *metadata = rep.metadata;
        if (metadata) {
            NSDictionary *GPSDict=metadata[@"{GPS}"];
            NSDictionary *TIFFDict=metadata[@"{TIFF}"];
            if (GPSDict){
                double longitude = [[GPSDict objectForKey:@"Longitude"] doubleValue];
                double latitude = [[GPSDict objectForKey:@"Latitude"] doubleValue];
                if ([[GPSDict objectForKey:@"LatitudeRef"] isEqualToString:@"S"]) {
                    latitude = -latitude;
                }
                if ([[GPSDict objectForKey:@"LongitudeRef"] isEqualToString:@"W"]) {
                    longitude = -longitude;
                }
                if (TIFFDict){
                    NSUserDefaults *pref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                    [pref setObject:[TIFFDict objectForKey:@"DateTime"] forKey:@"PHOTODATE"];
                    [pref synchronize];
                }
                coordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
            }else {

                latitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
                 longitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;

                 [GPSDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:fabs(latitude)]
                 forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude];
                 [GPSDictionary setObject:(latitude > 0 ? @"N": @"S") forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitudeRef];
                 [GPSDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:fabs(longitude)]
                 forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitude];
                 [GPSDictionary setObject:(longitude > 0 ? @"E": @"W") forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitudeRef];        //

                 if (metadata&& GPSDictionary) {
                 [metadata setValue:GPSDictionary forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary];
                 }
                 coordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        //User denied access
        NSLog(@"Unable to access image: %@", error);
    }];
```

I am using above code to get metadata of image.But now i want to edit this metadata.I want to add custom location in image if the location information is not present in the {GPS} dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

From the apple’s documentation : `Applications are only allowed to edit assets that they originally wrote.` So if your application is writing image in Photos Library then only you will be able to edit its metadata.

You can check whether metadata is editable or not using `ALAsset`’s `editable` property.

I was able to update metadata using `setImageData:metadata:completionBlock:` method.

Please refer following code :
I am passing same image data with updated metadata. Also I have tested changing orientation not the GPS data but this code helps  you to start :

```
ALAsset *asset = // your asset
    if(asset.editable) {
        NSDictionary *metadata = asset.defaultRepresentation.metadata;

        NSDictionary *gpsInfo=metadata[@"{GPS}"];

        if (gpsInfo) {
            NSMutableDictionary *mutableGPSInfo = [gpsInfo mutableCopy];
            [mutableGPSInfo setObject:@"yourNewLatitude" forKey:@"Latitude"];
            [mutableGPSInfo setObject:@"yourNewLongitude" forKey:@"Longitude"];

            NSMutableDictionary *mutableMetadata = [metadata mutableCopy];
            [mutableMetadata setObject:[mutableGPSInfo copy] forKey:@"{GPS}"];

            ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
            Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);
            NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:nil];
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];

            [asset setImageData:data metadata:[mutableMetadata copy] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                if (error) {
                    NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Asset metadata is successfully edited");
                }
            }];
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"oops..! Asset can not be edited");
    }
```